# Is it possible to list all created opened socket by a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, networking

Is it possible from inside a Node.js application to list all opened sockets (via the module net for example)?

Comment: did you search and not find anything?

Comment: I will have to wrap the net.createConnection method (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L69) and store sockets